# How to submit multiple form inputs as sets of serialized data?

Tags: php, serialization

```
$serialize_me = array(
    array(
      'Name' => 'English',
      'Apprev' => 'en',
      'default' => true,
    ),
    array(
      'Name' => 'عربي',
      'Apprev' => 'ar',
      'default' => false,
    ),
); 
$serialized = serialize($serialize_me);
```

Using this array, I'm able to serialize the data and insert it into a database. But how can I build such an array using a form?
I'm trying to build a form that will allow me to serialize the data and insert it into a database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

on the HTML side (called for example whatever.php):

```
<form action="action.php" method="post">
<?php
  $num_languages = 2; // Set this to the number of languages you want.
  for($x = 0; $x < $num_languages; $x++) {
?>
<input type="text" name="name[<?php echo $x; ?>]" />
<input type="text" name="apprev[<?php echo $x; ?>]" />
<input type="checkbox" name="default[<?php echo $x; ?>]" />
<?php } ?>
</form>
```

and then on the PHP side (in the case of this example a file called action.php):

```
<?php
  $array_serialize = array();
  foreach ($_POST['name'] as $key => $value) {
    $array_serialize[$key]['Name'] = $value;
    $array_serialize[$key]['Apprev'] = $_POST['apprev'][$key];
    $array_serialize[$key]['default'] = ($_POST['default'][$key] == 'on')?true:false;
  }
  $serialized = serialize($array_serialize); 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the name attribute like it was an array.  Like this:

```
<?php 

if($_POST)
{
    var_dump($_POST);
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post">
        <input name="in[0][name]" value="English" />
        <input name="in[0][apprev]" value="en" />
        <input name="in[0][default]" value="true" />

        <input name="in[1][name]" value="Other" />
        <input name="in[1][apprev]" value="ar" />
        <input name="in[1][default]" value="false" />
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, but how to get these inputs in an array like that one in the question in order to serialize it?

Comment: I edited the answer. When you run it, just click submit and you will see the array.

Answer (score 0):

When you send in a form, you have all sent-in fields available in an array, `$_POST` or `$_GET` depending on the method you are using.

You can serialize that array and store it in a database but I would definitely not recommend that as it makes data retrieval and manipulation unnecessary hard.

Looking at your example I would have a database table with (at least...) 3 fields, `Name`, `Apprev` and `default` and your example would add two rows to that table.

Comment: Yes but building a table for only holding two rows of data doesn't make sense, Not sure if I'm correct about this :)

Comment: @Mohamed Said One row (your serialized array...) even less ;-) If you are looking to store something like preferences (1 fixed set of information), you don't need a database, you can use a text-file instead.

Comment: @Mohamed Said If you are looking to add multiple sets / forms, you could always add a field that identifies that specific set (like a user ID, submission date, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

This code provide more portability in the PHP code, you can set the names of your data dynamically without changing the PHP code.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Form</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            $name = $_POST['name'];
            for ($i=0; $i<count($name); $i++) {
                foreach ($name[$i] as $k => $v) {
                    $serialize[$i][$k] = (($v=="1") ? TRUE : (($v=="0") ? FALSE : $v));
                }
            }
            $serialized = serialize($serialize);
        }
    ?>
    <form name="myform" method="POST">
        <!-- English Language -->
        <?php
            $max = 2;
            for ($i=0; $i<$max; $i++) {
        ?>
        <input type="text" name="name[<?php echo $i; ?>][Name]" value="English">
        <input type="text" name="name[<?php echo $i; ?>][Apprev]" value="en">
        <input type="text" name="name[<?php echo $i; ?>][default]" value="0">
        <?php
            }
        ?>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```